# "New update available, downloading..." on Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, android-emulator

After opening my React Native project in Expo, I get a "New update available, downloading..." infinite loading on the Android emulator.

I tried restarting the server and restarting the emulator, expecting to see the actual content of my React Native application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by following these steps:

1. Stop the server.
2. Uninstall Expo on Android emulator.
3. Run `npm start`.
4. Reopen the application on Android emulator.